# Create a python script that create a sql dump with structure and data file from mysql database

Tags: python, mysql

I want to make a backup script in python that make a .sql file with structure and data, and saves it on the disk?

The issue is that i wanna make a routine for a backup remotely, so the file will be stored in a different server.. To make sure that if my server dies, the data does not die with it.

Is it possible?

Comment: whew, what a comment

Comment: Such question deserves such comments.. But if you have some **specific** issue with this task, feel free to edit your question

Comment: Ah, yeah I see. I added it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't see why you want to do that in Python since there is already a command for that: [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html). If you specify it with:

```
mysqldump -u username -p database
```

It will query for your password and then write the SQL statements to the stdout.

You can use I/O redirection to write it to a file, like:

```
mysqldump -u username -p database > file.sql
```

Since SQL is a quite verbose language, you can also construct a zipped file, by passing the output through the `gzip` compressor:

```
mysqldump -u username -p database | gzip --best > file.sql.gz
```

If you want to "write" a program in Python that does the calls itself, you can do it with `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess

username = 'the_username'
password = 'the_password'
database = 'my_fancy_database'

with open('file.sql','w') as output:
    c = subprocess.Popen(['mysqldump', '-u',username,'-p%s'%password,database],
                         stdout=output, shell=True)
```

But this is only some logic around the `mysqldump` command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was what I was looking for. I'll mark is at solved in a few minutes

Comment: A full example can be found here: https://tecadmin.net/python-script-for-mysql-database-backup/

Comment: Keep in mind that you are using password at the command line, and it can be captured and saved in bash_history, and viewed by other users sharing the same privilege. A better option using mysqldump may be to make it read the details from a temporary auth file.

Comment: @JoelGMathew can you make a full example of that, based on the example in this answer?